# WPF Responsive Design

Tags: wpf, user-interface

I am creating WPF application with MAHAPPS.METRO UI. I am using GRID for designing window pages. The every grid rows and columns are fixed height and widths. The problem is when I am run a application in my machine(14" display) it showing perfect. Otherwise the application is incompatible to the bigger screens(above 15"). So I kindly need how to create responsive or compatible with all size of screens. Thankz..

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for `Liquid Layout` in WPF.

Avoid specifying explicit Width and Height for your elements and it should scale up to whatever screen resolution available.

Check these References:

- [Discussion on MSDN forums on same topic with lots of pointers](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d76685d3-d2de-495e-bcb8-77ccd948a0ab/resolution-independence?forum=wpf)
- [Is WPF Really Resolution Independent?](http://www.wpflearningexperience.com/?p=41)

Comment: Thanks for reply.. I have a more explanation about responsive design in WPF. Thank you..